# Passing data back from async in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm using `async` and trying to get data to pass back. Is this possible or do I need to use another library approach?

Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

`async.forEach(txids, processTransaction, function(asyncErr, outputTotal) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`async.reduce()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#reduce), similar to [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) but asynchronous.

The given example is:

```
async.reduce([1,2,3], 0, function(memo, item, callback){
    // pointless async:
    process.nextTick(function(){
        callback(null, memo + item)
    });
}, function(err, result){
    // result is now equal to the last value of memo, which is 6
});
```

You would probably do something similar to:

```
async.reduce(txids, {}, processTransaction, function(err, output) { });
```

I'm not sure what `processTransaction` returns, so I'm not sure what your `memo` (or `initialValue`) should be.